# Find Maximum Strength given number of elements to be skipped on left and right.Please Tell me why my code gives wrong output for certain test cases?

Tags: c++, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array "s" of "n" items, you have for each item an left value "L[i]" and right value "R[i]" and its strength "S[i]",if you pick an element you can not pick L[i] elements on immediate left of it and R[i] on immediate right of it, find the maximum strength possible.

Example input:

```
5            //n
1 3 7 3 7    //strength
0 0 2 2 2    //Left Value
3 0 1 0 0    //Right Value
```

Output:

```
10
```

Code:

```
#include < bits / stdc++.h >
using namespace std;

unsigned long int getMax(int n, int * s, int * l, int * r) {

    unsigned long int dyn[n + 1] = {};
    dyn[1] = s[1];
    for (int i = 2; i <= n; i++) {
        dyn[i] = dyn[i - 1];
        unsigned long int onInc = s[i];
        int left = i - l[i] - 1;

        if (left >= 1) {
            unsigned int k = left;
            while ((k > 0) && ((r[k] + k) >= i)) {
                k--;
            }
            if (k != 0) {
                if ((dyn[k] + s[i]) > dyn[i]) {
                    onInc = dyn[k] + s[i];
                }
            }
        }

        dyn[i] = (dyn[i] > onInc) ? dyn[i] : onInc;
    }
    return dyn[n];
}

int main() {

    int n;
    cin >> n;
    int s[n + 1] = {}, l[n + 1] = {}, r[n + 1] = {};
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> s[i];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> l[i];
    }
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
        cin >> r[i];
    }

    cout << getMax(n, s, l, r) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem in your approach:**

In your DP table, the information you are storing is about maximum possible so far. The information regarding whether the `ith` index has been considered is lost. You can consider taking strength at current index to extend previous indices **only if** any of the previously seen indices is either not in range or it is in range and has not been considered.

**Solution:**

Reconfigure your DP recurrence. Let `DP[i]` denote the maximum answer if `ith` index was considered. Now you will only need to extend those that satisfy range condition. The answer would be maximum value of all DP indices.

**Code:**

```
vector<long> DP(n,0); 

DP[0]=strength[0]; // base condition

    for(int i = 1; i < n ; i++){

        DP[i] = strength[i];

        for(int j = 0; j < i ; j++){

            if(j >= (i-l[i]) || i <= (j+r[j])){ // can't extend

            }
            else{

                DP[i]=max(DP[i],strength[i]+DP[j]); // extend to maximize result

            }
        }
    }

long ans=*max_element(DP.begin(),DP.end());
```

**Time Complexity:** O(n^2)

**Possible Optimizations:**

There are better ways to calculate maximum values which you might want to look into. You can start by looking into [Segment tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segment_tree) and [Binary Indexed Trees](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fenwick_tree).

Comment: Happy to help ... If my answer was helpful, you can accept the answer. If you have any more doubts you can ask so that I can edit my answer to clear it.